# SocketIO + Redis Connection Closed

Tags: laravel-5, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I followed the documentation provided, and it seems that the server isn't accepting the connection:

```
(failed)
net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

- I am using Laravel Horizon, and it appears to be running fine.
- If I manually use the **redis-cli** command to access the server, and
  apply the 'ping' command, I get a 'pong' response.

Server appears to be up and running after applying the **laravel-echo-server start** command:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.3.6

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!
```

**bootstrap.js:**

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
});
```

**.env:**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
{
    "authHost": "http://dialfy.local",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "dd4d563e7e81f442",
            "key": "1627b6fd226c7f3c866ca209f78779b6"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

Any idea on what the issue may be, or where I could start looking? I imagine it is a configuration issue, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into a similar problem: the reason was because my app was running on https locally, and I did not configure laravel-echo-server to do the same.